# DOMDocument->saveHTMLFile saving escaped text

Tags: php, html, dom, save, domdocument

I am trying to save a string of html into the nodeValue attribute of a DOMElement in PHP, but after I save the file with DOMDocument->saveHTMLFile the string of HTML is escaped and I can not figure out how to get the string not be saved as escaped text. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate more as to what is happening? Do you want the HTML syntax to show as `>` opposed to `&gt;`?

Comment: yes, the html is coming from a wysiwyg editor (e.g. <p>text</p>) and being put into the nodeValue attribute of a DOMElement object and it is appearing in the file as: &lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load that string of html with DOMDocument::loadHTML and append that to your node (appendChild).

Comment: This seems to be what I would be looking to do, after I parse the HTML string with loadHTML I am then trying to append it to the current element with this: $currElement->appendChild($html_dom_doc->documentElement) But I am getting an exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Wrong Document Error'

Comment: You can use importNode() method:
http://en.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php

Also, PHP's DOM has non-standard appendXML() method, it looks exactly what you need (not sure it will accept HTML, though).

Link with example:
http://en.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php